# dhclient-exit-hooks was not executed with NetworkManager

Tags: networkmanager

I configured `/etc/dhclient-exit-hooks`, in the old days, when I do `dhclient eth0` like stuff, that script got executed automatically.

Now I switched to NM, the script were never called! Althrough `ps` clearly shows it was running.

> /usr/sbin/dhclient -d -4 -sf
>   /usr/lib/networkmanager/nm-dhcp-client.action -pf
>   /var/run/dhclient-wlan0.pid -lf
>   /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-85e57415-affe-4375-921d-f2eb45bc1002-wlan0.lease
>   -cf /var/run/nm-dhclient-wlan0.conf wlan0

Any thoughts?

Comment: What if NetworkManager is not installed and still seeing the same problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NetworkManager has its own place for hooks in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`. Scripts in there get called whenever an interface changes state, see the [NetworkManager manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/networkmanager) for all gory details.